# Having problems requesting JSONP from a remote server. $.ajax() silently failing, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I am attempting to access a remote sever through a web API using the jQuery AJAX method.  The API is private and so I cannot give you the URL I am using but here is an example:

```
https://api.somecompany.com/v2/search?oauth_token=OAUTH_TOKEN&keyword=KEYWORD&limit=LIMIT
```

The API supports JSONP and informs the user that when using JSONP the URL format should be:

```
https://api.somecompany.com/v2/search?oauth_token=OAUTH-TOKEN&keyword=KEYWORD&limit=LIMIT&callback=callbackFunction
```

I know my Oauth token is valid because when I run the URL in the browser it displays the desired JSON and I know the JSON is valid because I have checked using JSONLint.  The format of the data in the browser using the second URL looks like this:

```
callbackFunction({
"meta":{...}
"items":[...]
})
```

I am attempting to get this data from the API in JSONP form using jQuery, but it doesn't seem to be working properly and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  The code that I am using is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <title>Template</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.somecompany.com/v2/search?oauth_token=OAUTH-TOKEN&keyword=KEYWORD&limit=10',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data)
                     {
                         alert('Success!');
                     },
            error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown){
                         alert(textStatus);
                   },
           complete: function(data, textSearch){
                        alert(data.resonseText);
                        alert(textStatus);
                     }
           });

    });     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<html>
```

The url is the same URL as the second example except with (callback=?).  I know it is hacky to write a full script within HTML code, but I am just trying to get this to start and it simplifies my work a bit.  When this code is run I get absolutely NO Alerts.  It doesn't even return an error on the console.  I tried this with another API that did not require a callback function and I received a success alert.  My guess is that it is something with the wrapper, but I am not quite sure what specifically is going wrong.  What am I doing wrong?  What do you suggest I try?  I am very new to JavaScript/jQuery so try to go easy on me if I am making amazingly stupid mistakes.  I have also tried doing this with $.getJSON() and have run into the same problem.  I have tried using console.log() within the functions and am not receiving any feedback. HELP!

Edit:  The url I used in the HTML doc has been updated.  It is as follows:

```
https://api.somecompany.com/v2/search?oauth_token=OAUTH-TOKEN&keyword=KEYWORD&limit=10
```

I have also tried using the url:

```
https://api.somecompany.com/v2/search?oauth_token=OAUTH-TOKEN&keyword=KEYWORD&limit=10&callback=?
```

That does not seem to work either.  The console only displayed:

```
GET http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 34ms]

GET http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 35ms]
```

Let me know if I should add anymore updates.

Comment: What does your `url` variable's contents look like? The code in the question, if used literally (as it looks like a complete test page), will fail because `url` is completely undefined. But I assume you've just trimmed things a bit too much for the question...

Comment: What do you see in the developer console?

Comment: Does the API actually return JSONP? We have no way to tell because you have obscured the URL and haven't show what it returns (which you should be able to extract using the Net tab in your developer tools).

Comment: Have you looked at the response tab of the request within the network tab? the fact that your console doesn't show an error is a bit surprising. It should either be calling success, or printing a syntax error in the console in the case of jsonp requests. (that or a network error, but you've already ruled that out)

Comment: Quentin:  Unfortunately, the api is proprietary information and I cannot give out the url.  Even if I did, the documentation is also private.  The documentation the APIs JSONP support is very small and I gave all of it in my own word above the HTML code.

Comment: Kevin B:  I am very surprised as well.  The network tab only shows the GET items for jQuery and jQuery UI.  I'm having a hard time figuring out my I'm not getting any sort of response back.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've actually included the `&callback=callbackFunction` part in the URL, because that's what their docs say.

You don't do that with jQuery, you let jQuery manage it for you. It will append a `callback` parameter with an auto-generated function name, auto-generate the function, and handle all the plumbing for you.

So your `url` should be `https://api.somecompany.com/v2/search?oauth_token=OAUTH-TOKEN&keyword=KEYWORD&limit=LIMIT` (without `&callback=callbackFunction`), and because you've told jQuery you're using JSONP, it'll do the other work for you.

Comment: I don't think I was quite clear in my explanation so I apologize, but I actually have tried the way you have mentioned before and I get the same response.  Do you have any other suggestions?